# Leaflet map view not in center

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I have this leaflet map and it keeps showing like this:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you make a plunker so we can see your code and help you.

Comment: This behaviour often happens when the size of your map container changes (for example it was on a hidden tab or so). If you are in that case, simply use [`invalidateSize()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize)